# API Graphic statistic PHP HTML CSS

Tags: php, css, api, graphic

I want to make a graphic with statistics. 
Like a money management on my cash to control my spending.

Is there a graphics (a good one) that i can insert in  a webpage (PHP HTML CSS)
and modify my data (week and money for example) for each week?
Or even a progress bar that i will control.

Thank you

Comment: This is a question that can be answered with a bare minimum of effort.  What have you searched for so far, and what have you found?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what level your programming is at but if you feel up to it, you could always try something like [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/). If you run into trouble with it you can always refer to the documentation or use SO :)